# What is the correct way to implement inheritance when dealing with classes in separate .cpp and .h files?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, syntax, header

I'm new to C++ and to practice I decided to write a simple console game. I originally wrote it all in the main.cpp file, but now I've decided to split all the classes up to make it simpler to read. I looked up a few tutorials on how to correctly do this but I seem to have run into an error that I haven't been able to find a solution to.

Here is a base class for a "block". Blocks of different textures inherit from this base block.

This is the code for the header file:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

class BaseBlock { //Base block class
private:
    int PosX, PosY;
protected:
    std::string Appearance;
    bool        IsActive;

public:
    BaseBlock(int x, int y);

    virtual inline int          getX();
    virtual inline int          getY();
    virtual inline bool         getIsActive();
    virtual inline std::string  getAppearance();
    virtual inline void         setActive(bool isactive);

};
```

Here is its .cpp file:

```
 #include "clsBaseBlock.h"



    BaseBlock::BaseBlock(int x, int y) {
        PosX        = x;
        PosY        = y;
        Appearance  = ' ';
        IsActive    = false;
    }

    inline int          BaseBlock::getX()                   { return PosX; }
    inline int          BaseBlock::getY()                   { return PosY; }
    inline bool         BaseBlock::getIsActive()            { return IsActive; }
    inline std::string  BaseBlock::getAppearance()          { return Appearance; }
    inline void         BaseBlock::setActive(bool isactive) { IsActive = isactive; }
```

Here is the code for the header of one of the derived classes:

```
 #pragma once
#include "clsBaseBlock.h"

class BlockWeak : public BaseBlock { // Third derived block class
public:
    BlockWeak(int x, int y) : BaseBlock(x, y) {} //Here is the inheritance
};
```

Here is its .cpp file:

```
  #include "clsBlockWeak.h"

BlockWeak::BlockWeak(int x, int y): BaseBlock(x,y){
        Appearance = "\xB1";
        IsActive = true;
    }
```

From this code I get all sorts of errors in the header file of the derived classes like:

-syntax error : 'symbol' : expected member function definition to end with '}'
-trailing 'char' illegal in base/member initializer list

Then in the .cpp file I get:

-type "int" unexpected
-unexpected end of file found

Any information on how to correct my code would be much appreciated.

Comment: you already defined the constructor of `BlockWeak` in the header, and then again in the source. Thats wrong also without inheritance and all code in a single file

Comment: What's the exact errors you're getting? [Edit] the question, and paste in the _exact_ error output by your compiler, including the line numbers for the errors. If necessary, indicate in the code in your question where those lines are.

Comment: `inline` means that the function may have a *definition* in more than one translation unit. All member functions are implicitly `inline`. It has nothing to with inlining of function *calls*, and there is no point in sprinkling it all over your code.

Comment: You need to fix errors in order of occurrence in each file. A very small problem, like a missing semicolon or a mismatched brace, can cause a huge cascade of incomprehensible follow-up errors.

Comment: Unrelated: Why `#include <iostream>` in `clsBaseBlock.h`? It's not needed in that file. Only include what's needed in the header file.

Comment: The code you've shown only generates _one_ error and that's the redefinition of the `BlockWeak` constructor that Armen talks about in the answer below. Without that redefinition, the above code [compiles fine](https://godbolt.org/z/sqfhW6fzq). You need to make a [mre] for us to be able to reproduce the other errors you talk about.

Comment: If I don't then include <iostream> it brings up an error saying that "string" is unrecognized.

Comment: @BigMike Ok, then `#include <string>`, not `<iostream>`

Answer (score 1):

```
BlockWeak(int x, int y) : BaseBlock(x, y) {} //Here is the inheritance
```

No, it's not. *Here* is the inheritance:

```
class BlockWeak : public BaseBlock
```

The following is a full definition of a constructor, which you have also provided in the .cpp file thus potentially breaking the One Definition Rule

```
BlockWeak(int x, int y) : BaseBlock(x, y) {}
```

You should probably remove the part starting from `:`, including the `{}` and move those into the definition

Comment: While this is a problem with the code, it is not the cause of the syntax errors in the question.

Comment: Thank you so so much. That did the trick. Everything works perfectly now.